# lighttpd, mod_rewrite and web.py unexpected behavior

Tags: python, mod-rewrite, lighttpd, web.py

I have configured lighttpd to work with web.py. Now I want to process all requests in the form **mysite.com/scripts/*** via my web.py script. This is how the related part of lighttpd.conf looks like:

```
fastcgi.server = ("/code.py" =>
(("socket" => "/var/tmp/lighttpd/fastcgi.socket",
  "bin-path" => "/var/www/code.py",
  "max-procs" => 1,
  "check-local" => "disable",
))
)

url.rewrite-once = (
  "^/scripts/(.*)$" => "/code.py/$1",
)
```

I set up a simple code.py that prints what appears in the URL. This is the code:

```
urls = (
    '(.*)', 'hello')

app = web.application(urls, globals(),True)

class hello:
    def GET(self, x):
        return "I have received: " + web.websafe(x)
```

When I enter **mysite.com/code.py/test**, I see **"I have received: /test"**, which is right, but when I enter **mysite.com/scripts/test**, I see **"I have received: /scripts/test"**.

I was expecting the rewrite rule to match what comes after /scripts/ and rewrite the URL as /code.py/test, why is it also passing the /scripts part?

Answer (score 0):

`"/scripts/test"` and `"/test"` are matched by `(.*)` as whole. If you want to match only the `"test"` part of both URLs, you may write something like this.

```
urls = (
  r'(.*)/(.*)', 'hello',
)

app = web.application(urls, globals(), True)

class hello(object):
  def GET(self, x, y):
    return 'i have received ' + web.net.websafe(y)
```

Comment: I believe the problem here is with lighttpd's url.rewrite-once rule, and not with web.py regexp. My assumption was that the URL "mysite.com/scripts/test" would match the rule "^/scripts/(.*)$" => "/code.py/$1", and rewrite the request as /code.py/test, but as I said in the original question, when I enter "http://mysite.com/scripts/test" I see "I have received: /scripts/test", which IMO means the URL is not rewritten correctly. web.py's regexp is meant to match everything, for debugging purposes.

Comment: I agree with dvvc.  If webpy propagates /code.py/foo to the application and the /foo part is used for matching, and the URL translation is "^/scripts/(.*)$" => "/code.py/$1", then /scripts/foo should translate to /code.py/foo, not /code.py/scripts/foo.